# I hope he (will) die

Tags: grammar, tense, present-tense, future-tense

In this following sentence:

Shall I say:

I hope he dies

Instead of saying :I hope she will die.

Besides, shall I say: "I hope she is cooking at 8." Instead of "I hope she will be cooking at 8"

Thanks so much!

Comment: What *grammar myth* (your tag) do you think you are dealing with?

Comment: "I hope he dies" is rarely a *pleasant* thing to say! When you use "8" do you mean "8 o'clock" or "8 years old"?

Answer (score 1):

After the verb *hope* you can  use any of the many ways to refer to future time, including

I hope she cooks at 8

I hope she's cooking at 8

I hope she will cook at 8

I hope she's going to cook at 8

I hope she'll be cooking at 8

I hope she's about to cook at 8

I hope she's to cook at 8

etc

Comment: Thanks so much for your help！ That means we can use “be doing something” to replace “will be doing？”

Answer (score 0):

The simple present can be used for future events seen as in evitable or following a timetable. "The train arrives at 8 o'clock". or "We all die". The same meaning could be given as "will arrive" or "will die" but the sense of certainty is lost.

This is still permitted with "hope". It is quite natural to use it with something widely seen as inevitable "I hope he dies". The second sentence could be phrased "is cooking" or "will be cooking", with almost no difference in meaning, though the first does suggest she is following a timetable or a plan.:

> We need to have everything ready for the party at 1pm, so *I hope she's* in the kitchen and *cooking by 8am*, otherwise the turkey won't have time to rest before carving.